# how to pass var inside callback request

Tags: javascript, node.js

i need to pass the var "surl", inside the callback request. I trying to do this, but the function start is called many times, and it changes surl value before the request gets done.

```
function start(bd){
    if(bd.length > 0){
        var zzz = bd.length-1;
        var sowner = bd[zzz].owner;
        var surl = bd[zzz].url;
        request({
            url: 'https://myurlapi/'+bd[zzz].owner+bd[zzz].url,
            followRedirect: false 
        }, function (error, response, body, surl) {
            console.log(surl);
        });
    }
}
```

**the surl var must to be passed exactly in the moment that the request is called, not when it is done.**

Comment: Dont pass it. surl will be closed in and you'll have access to it like normal.

Comment: It's already in closure so it will be already accessible, if you will pass it, it might make it `undefined`.

Comment: the problem is, I will call for the surl value, but it will already be changed, because the function start will be called again, before the request gets done.

Comment: That is not the problem. If it doesn't work then there is something more that you're not showing us.  Calling the function again would create a new surl, not change the old one.

Comment: right...
think in a asynchronous scene, this function will be called each 0,5 sec.
each call, the bd value will be change, so the surl too;
in the first call start, surl = 1, request one is queued;
second call start, surl = 2, but in this time request one have been done, it return 2, but should be 1;

Comment: No, the surl will not change. Each time you call the function it creates a new scope for variables to live in. They don't override each other. Look: http://jsfiddle.net/6vsj1mu4/

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the argument `surl` in your callback function to something else:

```
}, function (error, response, body, newUrl) {
           console.log(surl);
});
```